# How to plot vertical stacked graph from different text files?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, stacked-chart

I have 5 txt files which contain data give me the effect of increasing heat on my samples and I want plot them in a vertical stacked graph, Where the final figure is 5 vertical stacked chart sharing the same X-axis and each line in a separate one to reveal the difference between them.

I wrote this code:

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.axes._axes as axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


input_files = glob.glob('01-input/RR_*.txt')
for file in input_files:
    data = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, delimiter="\t").values
    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, linestyle=':')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.xlabel('x-axis')
    plt.ylabel('y-axis')
```

But the result is only one graph containing all the lines:

[image]

I want to get the following chart:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# just a dummy data
x = np.linspace(0, 2700, 50)
all_data = [np.sin(x), np.cos(x), x**0.3, x**0.4, x**0.5]

n = len(all_data)
n_rows = n
n_cols = 1
fig, ax = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols) # each element in "ax" is a axes

for i, y in enumerate(all_data):
    ax[i].plot(x, y, linewidth=2, linestyle=':')
    ax[i].set_ylabel('y-axis')
    # You can to use a list of y-labels. Example:
    # my_labels = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5']
    # ax[i].set_ylabel(my_labels[i])
    # The "my_labels" lenght must be "n" too

plt.xlabel('x-axis') # add xlabel at last axes
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I confused where you used 5 equations and I need to use the imported files. could you help me please?